# Resolving version conflicts between project and ant libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, jar

I am trying to build a large java project using Ant and Eclipse.  As such there are many referenced jar libraries, including asm.jar, which is used by Ant (and version 2.2.3 is by default in my ANT_HOME/lib).  Now it happens that I need a different version of asm.jar for my project (specifically, 3.0).

However, whenever I try to run my ant build script from the command line, it ends up loading asm-2.2.3.jar rather than asm-3.0.jar.  How do I resolve this conflict?

Details:

First, my build.xml file:

```
<project name="MyProject" default="all" basedir=".">

<property name="runtime.jar" value="mp3.jar"/>
<property name="src" location="src"/>
<property name="build" location="build"/>
<property name="dist" location="dist"/>
<property name="test" location="test/unit/src" />
<property name="testclasses" location="test/unit/classes" />

<property name="project.lib" location="lib"/>
<property name="project.lib.jar" location="${project.lib}/jars"/>
<property name="project.lib.conf" location="${project.lib}/conf"/>
<property name="project.lib.gameconfigs" location="gameconfigs"/>
<property name="project.lib.images" location="${project.lib}/images"/>
<property name="project.classes" location="${build}"/>

<property name="project.doc" location="doc"/>
<property name="project.doc.java" location="${project.doc}/javadoc"/>
<property name="project.src" location="src"/>
<property name="experiments.src" location="experiments"/> 
<property name="project.gui" location="gui"/>
<property name="project.agents" location="agents"/>
<property name="project.webctrl" location="webctrl"/>
<property name="project.web" location="webctrl/web"/>
<property name="project.webinf" location="webctrl/web/WEB-INF"/>

<path id="project.classpath">
    <fileset dir=".">
        <include name="lib/jars/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>

</path>

<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="lib/jars/junit-4.8.2.jar" />
    <pathelement location="${test}" />
    <pathelement location="${testclasses}" />
    <pathelement location="${project.classes}"/>
    <path refid="project.classpath" />
</path>

<!-- Import build specific targets for building MyProject -->
<import file="lib/conf/ant/ct-build.xml" as="ct-build"/>

</project>
```

Now, the relevant part of the referenced import:

```
<target name="init">
    <!-- Create the time stamp -->
    <tstamp/>
    <!-- Create the build directory structure used by compile -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
</target>

<available property="unjar.done" file="${build}/org/apache/log4j/Appender.class"/>

<target name="unjar" depends="init" description="unjar the jars" unless="unjar.done">
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/commons-codec-1.3.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/forms_rt.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/activemq-all-5.4.2.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/log4j-1.2.14.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/junit-4.8.2.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/asm.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <unjar src="${project.lib.jar}/javac2.jar" dest="${build}"/>
    <property name="unjar.done" value="true" />
</target>


<target name="compile" depends="unjar"
    description="compile the source " >
    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${build} -->
    <mkdir dir="${build}/gnu/getopt"/>
    <copy todir="${build}/gnu/getopt">
        <fileset dir="${src}/gnu/getopt">
            <include name="*.properties"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>


    <taskdef
            name="uidesigner"
            classname="com.intellij.uiDesigner.ant.Javac2"
            classpathref="project.classpath"/>

    <uidesigner
        destdir="${project.classes}"
        debug="on"
        source="1.5"
        includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="${project.src}"/>
        <src path="${project.gui}"/>
        <src path="${project.agents}"/>
        <src path="${experiments.src}"/>
        <include name="**/*.java"/>
        <include name="**/*.form"/>
        <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
        <classpath path="${project.src}"/>
        <classpath path="${project.classes}"/>
        <exclude name="misc/**"/>
        <exclude name="docs/**"/>
    </uidesigner>
</target>
```

It is worthy of note that writing this code in Eclipse gives me a warning that project.classpath cannot be found (in the imported file).  However, when running ant from the command line, it seems to have no problem locating Javac2.class.  Rather, I just get the error saying that a method in asm.jar is missing (which I have determined to be due to loading the wrong version).  See below:

```
compile:
[uidesigner] classpath=
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\build;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\activemq-all-5.4.2.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\asm-commons-3.0.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\asm.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\bcel.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\commons-codec-1.3.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\forms-1.1-preview.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\forms_rt.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\javac2.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\jdom.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\junit-4.8.2.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\log4j-1.2.14.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\jars\xerces.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\src;E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\build;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-launcher.jar;
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\.\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\activation-1.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-antlr.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-jai.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-javamail.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-jmf.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-jsch.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-junit.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-junit4.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-launcher.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-swing.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant-testutil.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\ant.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\asm-2.2.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\asm-commons-2.2.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\asm-tree-2.2.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\bcel-5.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\bsh-2.0b4.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\bsh-core-2.0b4.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\commons-logging-1.0.4.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\commons-logging-api-1.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\commons-net-1.4.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jai-codec-1.1.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jai-core-1.1.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jasper-compiler-4.1.36.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jasper-runtime-4.1.36.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jdepend-2.9.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jruby-0.9.8.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\js-1.6R7.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\jsch-0.1.50.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\junit-4.11.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\log4j-1.2.14.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\mail-1.4.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\maven-artifact-ant-2.0.4-dep.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\NetRexxC.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\oro-2.0.8.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\regexp-1.2.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\regexp-1.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\serializer-2.7.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\which-1.0.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\xalan-2.7.1.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;
E:\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\xml-resolver-1.2.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\lib\tools.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\resources.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\rt.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\jsse.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\jce.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\charsets.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext\localedata.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext;
C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar
BUILD FAILED
E:\Repositories\MyProject\mp3\lib\conf\ant\ct-build.xml:49: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.objectweb.asm.ClassWriter.<init>(I)V
    at com.intellij.ant.AntClassWriter.<init>(AntClassWriter.java:13)
    at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.instrumentForms(Javac2.java:134)
    at com.intellij.ant.Javac2.compile(Javac2.java:50)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

One final note: I don't know why ant is loading the Java 6 libraries instead of the Java 7.

Comment: FYI, I don't know what you are using asm for but asm 4.0 is required to manipulate Java 7 byte code.  Unfortunately, asm4 API is not backwards compatible with previous versions (many interfaces were turned into abstract classes!) This makes mixing and matching different versions of asm even harder.

Comment: I have run into that problem.  From what I can see, I actually need asm3 (for forms_rt.jar and javac2.jar, which are both from com.intellij).  Unfortunately, the latest version of ant that I downloaded appears to have asm2.2.3.  My problem is that the latter is loaded first, and my ant compiler never looks for the asm3.0 version to use with javac2.